# Trigger Firing During Inserting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hai I have created two tables one source table and other target table. I created a trigger to insert the hire date in target table if the hire date is greater than SYSDATE. But the date is not inserting in the target table.
Here is the query. Please correct my mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hir_trg
BEFORE INSERT
ON hir_tb
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO trg_tb VALUES (:NEW.h_date);
END;
/

DECLARE
v_date  DATE;
v_er    EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
v_date := &v_date;
dbms_output.put_line(v_date);
IF v_date > SYSDATE THEN
RAISE v_er;
END IF;
INSERT INTO hir_tb VALUES (103, 'abc', v_date, 25400);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN v_er THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('Not a Valid Date');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem but usage of `&v_date`, where you should format it with `quotations` and use `nls_date_format` (here, i assume as `dd.mm.yyyy`) of your database.

```
DECLARE
v_date  DATE;
v_er    EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
v_date := to_date('&v_date','dd.mm.yyyy');
dbms_output.put_line(v_date);
IF v_date > SYSDATE THEN
RAISE v_er;
END IF;
INSERT INTO hir_tb VALUES (103, 'abc', v_date, 25400);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN v_er THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('Not a Valid Date');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are raising exception first and then running the `INSERT`. It will never execute the `INSERT` this way when the condition is met. Add another insert within `IF..END IF` before `RAISE`.

```
IF v_date > SYSDATE THEN
INSERT INTO hir_tb VALUES (103, 'abc', v_date, 25400);
RAISE v_er;
END IF;
INSERT INTO hir_tb VALUES (103, 'abc', v_date, 25400);
```

Also remember that you must always mention the column names explicitly  in your `INSERT` statement to avoid confusion - `INSERT INTO yourtable(col1,col2,col3) VALUES (value1,value2,value3);`

**EDIT** :
You said,

> If I use the above code it is inserting in source table and target
>   table. But I need it to be inserted only in target table.

Add the insert into target table in exception block and remove the insert within `IF..END IF`. There is no need of `TRIGGER`.

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN v_er THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('Not a Valid Date');
    INSERT INTO trg_tb VALUES (v_date);
END;
```

Comment: If I use the above code it is inserting in source table and target table. But I need it to be inserted only in target table.

Comment: @SRamPrakash : I have updated the answer. You don't triggers if that is the case.

Comment: @SRamPrakash : Please do read -  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers   and the answer

Comment: Can you please help me to provide a real time scenario on procedures, functions and packages.